# Automating Script Creation for Many Files

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

I am having trouble figuring away around this.  I have some genetics files I need to filter.  Due to the way my cluster is setup, It will time out before I can filter all the files/samples in the VCF.  Therefore, that means I have to manually write close to 1,250 scripts to do this properly.  Obviously, copy-paste and manually changing them in Notepad++ is possible to get the proper chromosomes is possible, but I would prefer not to sit at my desk for a full day straight doing CTRL-C, CTRL-H, CTRL-S.  I want to automate this so I can take the base script, modify what I need, and save these to a new file.  I have the basics down but I am not sure how to compile all of this together and Google has lead me nowhere.

My file looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #SBATCH stuff

    cd /Where/My/Stuff/Is/

    while read i; do

    ./bcftools view Chrom1.vcf --options-for-bcftools -S 
    /Where/My/Samples/Are/${i}_Samples.txt -o 
    /Where/I/Want/NewFile/To/Go/${i}_Chrom1.vcf; done < /Where/My/Samples/Are/FullSampleList.txt
```

What I am thinking, and where I need input, is to have something like:

```
    for x in {1..22}; do

    cat Script1.sh

    sed 's/./bcftools view Chrom${x}.vcf --options-for-bcftools -S /Where/My/Samples/Are/${i}_Samples.txt -o /Where/I/Want/NewFile/To/Go/${i}_Chrom1.vcf; done < /Where/My/Samples/Are/FullSampleList.txt Script1.sh > Script2.sh; done
```

I could really use some help.  The resultant script name should be Script[previousnumber+1].sh, so the file names will increase in increments of 1.  There has to be a way to do this, I can't imagine people sit and copy-paste all day if they have hundreds of scripts they need to submit working on specific files.

Comment: What are the actual commands you want to run? What are the file names? Do you really have no data for the sex and mitochondrial chromosomes? What is in `/Where/My/Samples/Are/FullSampleList.txt`? Is it full paths or only file names? Why don't you just combine the separate chromosome vcf files into one vcf?

Comment: @terdon I apologize, but I am not really sure why much of this relevant to my question.  The BCFTools commands and what are inside the files are irrelevant if the command is identical and I just want to loop over them and substitute Chrom1.vcf for Chrom2.vcf when it creates Script2., Chrom3.vcf in Script 3, etc.  The file names are appended at the end of the paths I have written.  I do not have sex chromosomes or mtDNA data as it is not relevant to what I am analyzing at this time.

Comment: Fair enough. I asked because you had chromosomes 1-22 so it looked like human and we usually have both sex chromosome and mitochondrial data. I was asking because all this seems absurdly complicated and I am trying to find ways to help you simplify it. Yes, you can generate thousands of scripts, but that is very unlikely to be the best solution. Do you have a few minutes to get into a chat room? I'm sure I can help you find a more efficient approach (I work with this kind of thing every day). If you do have time/want to, give me a ping here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## Set the scriptHeader variable to hold the SBATCH commands you need
read -r -d '' scriptHeader <<EoF
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH line 1
#SBATCH line 2
#SBATCH line 3
EoF

stuffPath=/Where/My/Stuff/Is
samplePath=/Where/My/Samples/Are
outputPath=/Where/I/Want/NewFile/To/Go


while read sampleName; do
  for ((chr=1; chr<=22; chr++)); do 
    command="$stuffPath/bcftools view"
    inVCF="$thisSamplePath/$chr.vcf"
    thisSamplePath="$samplePath/${sampleName}_Samples.txt"
    thisOutputPath="$outputPath/${sampleName}_Chrom${chr}.vcf"

    printf '%s\n%s "%s" -S "%s" -o "%s"\n' "$scriptHeader" \
           "$command" "$inVCF"\
           "$thisSamplePath/$chr.vcf" \
           "$thisOutputPath" > "$stuffPath/$sampleName.$chr.sh"
  done
done < "$samplePath"/FullSampleList.txt
```

This will produce 22 files for each line in `"$samplePath"/FullSampleList.txt`. Each file will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SBATCH line 1
SBATCH line 2
SBATCH line 3
/Where/My/Stuff/Is/bcftools view "/Where/My/Samples/Are/ACB_YRI_Samples.txt/6.vcf" -S "/Where/My/Samples/Are/ACB_YRI_Samples.txt/6.vcf" -o "/Where/I/Want/NewFile/To/Go/ACB_YRI_Chrom6.vcf"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the trick!!!